# cerrar un formulario desde otro en visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Deseo cerrar un formulario desde otro pero no he podido he usado los siguientes métodos estando en el form2 pero no hace nada:

1.- form1.close()

2.- Dim form As New form1
    form.close()

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme llevo días investigando la manera de poder hacerlo pero no he podido. De antemano gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías darnos más información sobre tu problema? ¿Cómo creas los forms nuevos?¿Existe alguna dependencia entre estos? ¿Cuál es el objetivo del programa (Por qué es necesario cerrar el form1...)?... Esto nos serviría para poder ayudarte mejor ;)

Comment: el form1 y form 2 los abro dentro de un panel que esta en otro formulario, lo que deseo es que al abrir uno de los dos paneles se cierre el otro

Answer (score 1):

Si estas mostrando el form usando el método `Show()`, puedes usar [Close()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Form_Close) para cerrarlo (y no necesitas usar .Dispose() ).

Te sugiero revisar la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Form_Close)

**Las dos condiciones cuando un formulario no se desecha usando el método `Close()` es cuando**:

> 1) es parte de una aplicación de interfaz de documentos múltiples
>   (MDI) y el formulario no está visible;
>
> 2) ha mostrado el formulario utilizando ShowDialog. En estos casos,
>   deberá llamar a `Dispose()` manualmente para marcar todos los controles
>   del formulario para la recolección de basura.

Por lo tanto en este caso te sugiero usar:

.[Dispose()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dispose?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

yo tuve un problema igual, y encontré en internet la solución.
Mi problema era el siguiente.

tenia dos Form, Form1 y Form2, Al cerrar Form1 todo estaba bien, pero al cerrar el Programa desde Form2, Este seguía en segundo plano.

La solución que encontré es el siguiente, Visual Studio. En explorador de soluciones esta del lado derecho. hay que dar click derecho sobre el nombre del proyecto, luego click en propiedades.
luego seleccionar Aplicaciones, Dentro de aplicaciones seleccionar en modo de apagado la opción "Al Cerrar El Ultimo Formulario"

Luego dentro del form1, al llamar el form2 hay que cerrar el form1

form2.Show()
Me.Close()

Listo a mi me funciono, pude cerrar la aplicación desde otro Form.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: David, excelente solución, solo agregaría un detalle, si el formulario que quieres cerrar se encuentra en un módulo de ensamblado entonces el proceso que describiste lo tienes que hacer en el módulo de ensamblado. Gracias y Saludos